# Designing a PID controller for a Type 1 System

Tags: pid-control

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this so I'll give it a try.
Given the following system, for example
$$
P(s) = \frac{40}{s(s+4)},
$$
I have to design a PID controller that must satisfy the following requests:

- the error for a unit ramp signal must be $ e_{r} \leq{0.2} $;
- the overshoot $ s\% \leq 20\%$;
- the rise time must be $ t_{s} \leq 1s $.

Lokking at the last two requests, I need the margin phase and the gain crossover frequency; if we use translate these closed-loop requests in open-loop requests, we have
$$
M_{\phi} \approx 45°
$$
$$
w_{t} = gain \; crossover \; frequency = 2.05 \;rad/s \;.
$$

From time domain to frequency domain, we have
$$
P(jw) = \frac{40}{jw(4+jw)},
$$
se we can calculate the modulus and phase of $P(jw)$:
$$
|P(jw_t)| = 4.34 \neq 1 \; \rightarrow \text{we need the Proportional component of the PID} 
$$
$$
\angle{P(jw)} = -117.13° \; \rightarrow \text{the actual } M_{\phi} \text{ is } 62.87°, \text{ so we need a delay of } 17.87°.
$$

As for now, the controller has the form of $C(s) = K$.
$$
K = \frac{1}{|P(jw)|} cos(-17.87°) = 0.22.
$$

The problem is about the first request.

$$
e_{r} \leq 0.2 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{k_{v}} \leq 0.2 \Rightarrow k_{v} \geq 5
$$
$$
k_v = \lim_{s\rightarrow 0} sKP(s) = \lim_{s\rightarrow 0} s \frac{40 \cdot 0.22}{s(s+4)} = 2.2 \not\geq 5.
$$

I heard from a teacher that in order to resolve this issue we can add the derivative component $D$, just to get a good $k_{v}$, but I don't know how to proceed in order to get the parameter $\tau_{D}$ of the $D$ component.

Any suggestions?